# MVC getting exception specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting an exception `specified cast is not valid` when trying to execute an SQL query which is returning values when I tried to execute in SQL Server IDE. The data type of AHT is `float` and for DID is `nvarchar` Here's the code which I'm getting the error:

```
while (reader.Read()){
  SomeDetails details = new LiveAHTDetails();
  details.AHT = reader.GetFloat(0);
  details.DID = reader.GetString(1);
  // another codes
}
```

Here's My Model:

```
public class SomeDetails
{
    public SomeDetails() { }

    public float AHT { get; set; }
    public string DID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: on which like is error thrown

Comment: the first one, then If i removed it then it's thrown on the second one: 
 details.AHT = reader.GetFloat(0);
  details.DID = reader.GetString(1);

Comment: Kindly add screenshot of output of your sql query. It will give us pin direcrtly to the problem.

Comment: Try reader.getsqldouble as per microsoft documentation

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare AHT as Double according to this page 
[SQL Server DataType Mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)

```
public double AHT { get; set; }
```

Hope this will help you
Regards

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer.

You should use double.

Also please try to use column names like this for precision

```
            string data= string.Empty;
            int indeks = read.GetOrdinal("columnname");
            if (!read.IsDBNull(indeks))
            {
                data= read.GetString(indeks);
            }
```

Also you can use your sql query like

```
Select datacolumn as AHT from ...
```

Comment: The data type of AHT is float and for DID is nvarchar in DB. Tried double also and it didn't work